# Is there anyway to Handle Empty response in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, caching, empty-list

I have been trying to fetch recommendation details from API Like top 5 matching

Colab code for in detail understanding

[cached based API calling](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1c7MAHQlJR7BohcdBmmHgKd6P6y84SCDQ?usp=sharing%5D)

Input : Smile value : O=C(N1C=CN=C1)NC2=NC(C)=C(C3=CC=C(S(=O)(C)=O)C(F)=C3)S2
output
Reac = NC1=CSC=C1C(OC)=O.O=C(Cl)CCl Reag = CCN-CC.C(Cl)Cl
Reac = NC1=CSC=C1C(OC)=O.O=C(Cl)CCl Reag = []
Reac = NC1=CSC=C1C(OC)=O.O=C(Cl)CCl Reag = CCN-CC.C(Cl)Cl
Reac = NC1=CSC=C1C(OC)=O.O=C(Cl)CCl Reag = []

This is value

```
reac - ['O=C(OC(C)(C)C)NCCC(NC(C)(C)C)=O', 'O=[C]C(F)(F)F']
reag - ['']
```

While got Empty value in reag variable it throws error message

```
   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

My actual logic is here

```
from cachetools import cached
from diskcache import Cache


BASE_URL = "https://ai.chemistryinthecloud.com/smilies/"
CACHEDIR = "api_cache"

@cached(cache=Cache(CACHEDIR))
def get_similies(value):
    return requests.get(BASE_URL + value).json()

def parse_eq(eq):
    reac, _, reag = (list(v.split(".")) for v in eq.partition(">"))
    print("reac -",reac)
    print("reag -",reag)
    print(type(reag[0]))
    return {
        "reactants": {i: get_similies(i) for i in reac},
        "reagents": {i: get_similies(i) for i in reag if i is not None}
    }

result = [parse_eq(eqs) for eqs in l]
```

How Can I skip the empty value and go to the next loop value?

Comment: Define 'empty' does it contain None, '', or something else?  Look at either ```try except``` methods, or ```if```